# Webservice with Hibernate+MySql performance

Tags: mysql, performance, web-services, hibernate

I have Java (Axis2) webservice with Hibernate as DAL.
Using InnoDB as the MySql engine.

I have few questions ergarding the performance:
 1. usually the fetching is fast, but the time takes may vary, sometimes it takes too much time to query? 
What usually takes time to query is the following query:
 1 Webservice request to get user info - we do it on users table, doing search - "where name like . 
 1 Webservice request to get user recipes (query recipe, where r.user.userId == userId, userId is given in the webservice)
2. How to configure c3p0 connection pool to get best performance?

This taken from hibernate.cfg

```
<property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
  <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
  <property name="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>

  <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">280</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
  <!-- this property forces the revalidation of a connection after the given amount of time (in secs) -->
  <!-- it must be set to LESS than the wait_timout setting for the mysql server (this setting defaults to 28800 secs (8 hours)) -->
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
```

Following are the hbm.xml files used when calling the 2 methods...
This is user.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 21:48:14 27/03/2012 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.icdb.data.User" table="user" catalog="yoavDB">
        <id name="userid" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="userid" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="birthdate" type="string">
            <column name="birthdate" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="string">
            <column name="password" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="firstname" type="string">
            <column name="firstname" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastname" type="string">
            <column name="lastname" length="50" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="country" type="string">
            <column name="country" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="numOfRecipes" type="int">
            <column name="numOfRecipes" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="picUrl" type="string">
            <column name="picUrl" length="200" />
        </property>
        <property name="rate" type="float">
            <column name="rate" precision="12" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="fewWords" type="string">
            <column name="fewWords" length="200" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="whatscooking" type="string">
            <column name="whatscooking" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="usermessagesesForSenderUserId" table="usermessages" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="senderUserId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Usermessages" />
        </set>
        <set name="usermessagesesForUserId" table="usermessages" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="userId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Usermessages" />
        </set>
        <set name="timelines" table="timeline" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="userId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Timeline" />
        </set>
        <set name="generaltipses" table="generaltips" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="authorid" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Generaltips" />
        </set>
        <set name="userlastvisitsForVisitedUserId" table="userlastvisit" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="visitedUserId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Userlastvisit" />
        </set>
        <set name="recipes" table="recipe" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="ownerid" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Recipe" />
        </set>
        <set name="userlikeses" table="userlikes" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="userId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Userlikes" />
        </set>
        <set name="friendshiptablesForUserBId" table="friendshiptable" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="userB_Id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Friendshiptable" />
        </set>
        <set name="usersForFavUserId" table="userfavchefsync" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="userId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="com.icdb.data.User">
                <column name="favUserId" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
        <set name="friendshiptablesForUserAId" table="friendshiptable" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="userA_Id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Friendshiptable" />
        </set>
        <set name="usersForUserId" table="userfavchefsync" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="favUserId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="com.icdb.data.User">
                <column name="userId" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
        <set name="activitylogsForObjectUserId" table="activitylog" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="objectUserId" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Activitylog" />
        </set>
        <set name="userlastvisitsForGuestUserId" table="userlastvisit" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="guestUserId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Userlastvisit" />
        </set>
        <set name="userrecipessyncs" table="userrecipessync" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="userId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Userrecipessync" />
        </set>
        <set name="activitylogsForUserId" table="activitylog" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="userId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Activitylog" />
        </set>
        <set name="recipereviews" table="recipereview" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="reviewerid" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Recipereview" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is recipe.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 21:48:14 27/03/2012 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.icdb.data.Recipe" table="recipe" catalog="yoavDB">
        <id name="recipeid" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="recipeid" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="user" class="com.icdb.data.User" fetch="select">
            <column name="ownerid" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="releasedate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="releasedate" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="preparationtime" type="int">
            <column name="preparationtime" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="recipedifficulty" type="int">
            <column name="recipedifficulty" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="50" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="description" type="string">
            <column name="description" length="200" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastupdated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="lastupdated" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="servecount" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="servecount" />
        </property>
        <property name="complete" type="boolean">
            <column name="complete" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="category" type="int">
            <column name="category" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="numOfViews" type="int">
            <column name="numOfViews" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="indexOfRecipeOfUser" type="int">
            <column name="indexOfRecipeOfUser" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="picUrl" type="string">
            <column name="picUrl" length="200" />
        </property>
        <property name="numOfLikes" type="int">
            <column name="numOfLikes" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="calculatedRate" type="float">
            <column name="calculatedRate" precision="12" scale="0" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="userlastvisits" table="userlastvisit" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="lastViewedRecipeId" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Userlastvisit" />
        </set>
        <set name="recipeingredients" table="recipeingredient" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="recipeid" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Recipeingredient" />
        </set>
        <set name="recipereviews" table="recipereview" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="recipeid" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Recipereview" />
        </set>
        <set name="userlikeses" table="userlikes" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="recipeId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Userlikes" />
        </set>
        <set name="activitylogs" table="activitylog" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="objectRecipeId" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Activitylog" />
        </set>
        <set name="userrecipessyncs" table="userrecipessync" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="recipeId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Userrecipessync" />
        </set>
        <set name="recipeinstructions" table="recipeinstruction" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="recipeid" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.icdb.data.Recipeinstruction" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

friendship table:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 21:48:14 27/03/2012 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.icdb.data.Friendshiptable" table="friendshiptable" catalog="yoavDB">
        <composite-id name="id" class="com.icdb.data.FriendshiptableId">
            <key-property name="userAId" type="int">
                <column name="userA_Id" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="userBId" type="int">
                <column name="userB_Id" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="userByUserAId" class="com.icdb.data.User" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="userA_Id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="userByUserBId" class="com.icdb.data.User" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="userB_Id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="status" type="short">
            <column name="status" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="statusLastChangedDate" type="date">
            <column name="statusLastChangedDate" length="10" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

LastVisit:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 21:48:14 27/03/2012 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.icdb.data.Userlastvisit" table="userlastvisit" catalog="yoavDB">
        <composite-id name="id" class="com.icdb.data.UserlastvisitId">
            <key-property name="guestUserId" type="int">
                <column name="guestUserId" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="visitedUserId" type="int">
                <column name="visitedUserId" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <many-to-one name="userByVisitedUserId" class="com.icdb.data.User" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="visitedUserId" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="userByGuestUserId" class="com.icdb.data.User" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
            <column name="guestUserId" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="recipe" class="com.icdb.data.Recipe" fetch="select">
            <column name="lastViewedRecipeId" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="lastVisitTimeStamp" type="timestamp">
            <column name="lastVisitTimeStamp" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Java code to fetch userInfo:

```
public String[] getUserInfo(    int visitingUserId,
                                int visitedUserId )
{
    Session session = ICDBHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try
    {
        session.beginTransaction();

        User                user    = (User) session.get(User.class, visitedUserId);
        ArrayList<String>   ret     = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Username
        ret.add( user.getFirstname() + " " + user.getLastname() );

        // Few words
        ret.add( user.getFewWords() );

        // Num of recipes
        ret.add( Integer.toString( user.getNumOfRecipes() ) );

        // Calculated Rank
        ret.add( Float.toString( user.getRate() ) );

        // Pic url
        ret.add( user.getPicUrl() );

        FriendshiptableId   id = new FriendshiptableId( visitingUserId, visitedUserId );
        Friendshiptable     ft = (Friendshiptable)session.get( Friendshiptable.class, id );
        if( ft == null )
        {
            id = new FriendshiptableId( visitedUserId, visitingUserId );
            ft = (Friendshiptable)session.get( Friendshiptable.class, id );
            if( ft == null )
            {
                ret.add( "none" );
            }
            else
            {
                FriendshipRequestStatusEnum status = FriendshipRequestStatusEnum.values()[ ft.getStatus() ];
                switch( status )
                {
                    case PENDING:
                        ret.add( "pending" );
                        break;

                    case ACCEPTED:
                        ret.add( "accepted" );
                        break;

                    case DECLINED:
                        ret.add( "declined" );
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FriendshipRequestStatusEnum status = FriendshipRequestStatusEnum.values()[ ft.getStatus() ];
            switch( status )
            {
                case PENDING:
                    ret.add( "pending" );
                    break;

                case ACCEPTED:
                    ret.add( "accepted" );
                    break;

                case DECLINED:
                    ret.add( "declined" );
                    break;
            }
        }

        if( visitingUserId != -1 )
        {
            // Has new stuff....
            UserlastvisitId ulvId   = new UserlastvisitId( visitingUserId, visitedUserId );
            Userlastvisit   ulv     = (Userlastvisit) session.get( Userlastvisit.class, ulvId );
            if( ulv == null )
            {
                // Lets add a new entry
                User visitingUser   = (User) session.load( User.class, visitingUserId );
                User visitedUser    = (User) session.load( User.class, visitedUserId );

                ulv = new Userlastvisit(    ulvId, 
                                            visitingUser, 
                                            visitedUser, 
                                            new Date() );
                session.save( ulv );

                ret.add( "true" );
            }
            else
            {
                List<?> loginResult= session.createQuery("from Recipe r where r.lastupdated >= :lastVisited" )
                        .setDate( "lastVisited", ulv.getLastVisitTimeStamp() )
                        .list();
                if( loginResult.size() > 0 )
                {
                    ret.add( "true" );
                }
                else
                {
                    ret.add( "false" );
                }

                // We need to update the last visit time...
                ulv.setLastVisitTimeStamp( new Date() );
                session.save( ulv );
            }
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        String[] retStr = new String[ret.size()];
        ret.toArray( retStr );

        return retStr;
    }
    catch( RuntimeException e )
    {
        ICDBHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

getuserRecipes method:

```
public String[] getUserRecipesNew(  int     visitingUserId,
                                        int     userId,     
                                        int     pageNumber )
    {
        final int       PAGE_SIZE   = 20;

        Session session = ICDBHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        try
        {
            session.beginTransaction();

            String hql = "from Recipe r where r.user.userid= :userid";

            Query query = session.createQuery( hql )
                                .setInteger(    "userid",       userId );

            query = query.setFirstResult( PAGE_SIZE * (pageNumber - 1) );
            query.setMaxResults( PAGE_SIZE );

            List<?> recipes = query.list();

            ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
            if( recipes.size() == PAGE_SIZE )
            {
                // Indicates that might be more results
                ret.add( "true" );
            }
            else
            {
                // No more results
                ret.add( "false" );
            }

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

            // Format the Recipes into string
            for( int i = 0; i < recipes.size(); i++ )
            {
                UserlikesId     userLikeId  = new UserlikesId( userId, ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getRecipeid() );
                Userlikes       userLike    = (Userlikes) session.get( Userlikes.class, userLikeId );

                ret.add( Integer.toString( ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getRecipeid() ) );
                ret.add( ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getName() );
                ret.add( ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getDescription() );
                ret.add( ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getUser().getFirstname() + ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getUser().getLastname() );
                ret.add( Integer.toString( ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getRecipedifficulty() ) );
                ret.add( Integer.toString( ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getServecount() ) );
                ret.add( Integer.toString( ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getPreparationtime() ) );
                ret.add( Integer.toString( ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getUser().getUserid() ) );
                ret.add( Integer.toString( ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getNumOfViews() ) );
                ret.add( df.format( ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getReleasedate() ) );
                ret.add( (((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getPicUrl() == null) ? "" : ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getPicUrl() );
                ret.add( Integer.toString( ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getCategory() ) );
                ret.add( (userLike==null)?"0":(userLike.isIsLike()?"1":"0") );
                ret.add( Integer.toString( ((Recipe)recipes.get(i)).getNumOfLikes() ) );
            }

            session.getTransaction().commit();

            String[] retStr = new String[ret.size()];
            ret.toArray( retStr );

            return retStr;
        }
        catch( RuntimeException e )
        {
            ICDBHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Is everything written OK? 
How should tune it to better performance?

Comment: have you considered caching.. i don't see any mention of using a 2nd level cache.. that will surely improve performance...

Comment: Can you explain how to use 2nd level caching please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by measuring what takes time. Then try to optimize where needed.

If your pool is too small, and you have more concurrent requests than the pool has connections, there will obviously be delays. The nest probable culprit is the query:

- turn SQL logging on and see if all the SQL queries are necessary (no unnecessary eager fetching)
- examine the execution plan of these queries in MySQL, and see if no index is missing.

Reading your code quickly, you're doing a manual N + 1 query:

1. query for recipes
2. for each recipe, find a Userlikes

You should use a single query to load all the needed data in one single query. Or at the very least, you should do a single query to load all the Userlikes at once, by using a `where id in (:setOfUserLikesIds)` clause.

Comment: can you please give example how to get all likes ar once? I have no idea ho to do it

Comment: As I said: you put all the IDs in a collection, and you execute a query which does `select ul from UserLikes ul where ul.id in (:setOfUserLikesIds)`.